# ArcGIS Server SOC Cannot Connect To Data

Tags: arcgis-server, error

I've been successfully publishing services to AGS.  SOC is set up to view all the data that is used in published services.  All of a sudden, I can no longer publish a service and have recieved the following error.

> Possible cause of connection failure: the soc cannot resolve the path to the data, or the soc account has not been granted read permissions of the data. In the case of ArcSDE, direct connect may not be configured properly, or the soc account may not have permission to access the database.

These are some things I have noticed:

1. If I drag and drop data into a new map document from an existing successfully published map, it works.  If I add that same dataset, but from Catalog, it does not work.
2. All the data from a successfully published map is referenced via a UNC Path and show up as medium warnings when analyzed through the publishing tool.  If I add a dataset from Catalog (or Add Data tool) and analyze the map, it indicates that it is not referenced via a UNC path.
3. If I create a map document that contains a dataset (again, dragged and dropped from a successuflly published map) that is UNC referenced and a dataset add through Catalog/Add Data Tool, it will publish but will leave out the dataset that is not UNCed.

From the image below, the three layers come from the same GDB.  The top layer was dragged and dropped from another map document and will show up in the published service.  The bottom layer is the same dataset except it is add to the map through the Add Data tool.  This is where the above error is coming from. 
[image]

All data that is brought in from Catalog/Add Datat tool is no longer UNC referenced.

Looks like something broke, any thoughts? Maybe reboot AGS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning **10027** “Layer’s data source is referenced via a UNC path” when you use the Analyze Button on the Map Service Publishing toolbar. ArcGIS Server likes local file system path names, but this can create problems when trying to access data on your network. The best way to get around this is to **make the source paths the same whether you open the mxd on your local box or on the server**. Mapped drives to shares do not give this warning. The easiest way to solve this is to find a drive letter which is not being used on the server and your personal machine. Share the proper folder and map to the share with the same drive letter on both machines. The mxd will open properly on both machines and will allow you to publish using either ArcGIS Server Manager on the server or ArcCatalog from your personal machine.

Comment: I believe our configurations are the same as what you have recommended.  One thing i've done is changed the map properties source data to relative paths.  This has helped but I'm not sure if it's addressing the real issue.

Answer (score 1):

Put mxd file in a shared folder accessible by SOC account and Try to publish the map document using UNC. By right clicking arcgis server node in arccatalog and select Add New Service... . Then add path to mxd file using UNC path. update us with the result.